# HtmlInputRadioButton when disabled does not gray out the labels

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, htmlcontrols

I am using in ASP.NET HtmlInputRadioButton runat = server dont ask why not RadioButtonList. Some one else's code and when I use disabled property it grays out the control but the labels are not grayed out and hence a defect. Any way to disable this control similar to RadioButtonList.Enabled = false in terms of visual experience?

Answer (score 0):

With your Enable=false, change the style of the text color to #777777, or other, to gray out the text.

This is not done automatically, because actually asp.net leave that to the browser, to show the disabled status, but for the moment the browsers did not show disabled, the connected with the radio buttons, text.